# Default Attribute Set has been populated with 'non default' Attributes - how to restore the factory default?

Tags: magento-1.9, attribute-set

I'm practicing on a test shop (1.9.1.0) which has seen others taking first steps in Magento before. So, things are not in any sort of 'clean page' status any longer. One example: The `default` Attribute Set has been populated with many attributes which are pretty particular, so it seems someone has changed the default Attribute Set.

Is it possible to create a new attribute set and set it to the 'Magento default' (if such a thing exists) somehow? Coppying the existing `defaulta´ Set does not help due to hat I've mentioned before.

Comment: What do you mean with particular? You can't remove them from the default set? What is your aspiration?

Comment: Aspiration is to see what the 'factory default' Attribute Set contains. i.e. there is an Attribute suitable for e-cigarettes in the 'default' Attribute Set on the test store I am playing with. I am sure this is not the 'factory default' (by that I mean the attributes that are in the default Attroibute Set on a fresh installation of Magento) but many others are not that obvious. So (if possible) I'd create a new Attribute Set using the 'factory defaults'. As I am just starting to understand things it'll be helpful to know what is 'default' and what not.

Comment: Have you tried to install a new local installation of the 1.9.1.0. There you can see the real default. you can get the version here https://magento.com/tech-resources/download?icid=topnav

Comment: true, that'd work. but if I could avoid a new install just to see what the factory-default is ... I would :-)

Comment: If you use xxamp you need just a few minutes. And you can use this "sandbox" for other practicing ;)